# how to use fromstring for xml parsing by ElementTree using python?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, elementtree

xml code is this

```
<foo>
<bar key="value">text</bar>
</foo>
```

Python code is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml=ET.fromstring(contents)
xml.find('./bar').attrib['key']
```

**Output: 'value'**

What must be placed in contents place of the  above python code to get the value as output?

If i write as contents only it is giving an error as contents not defined.

Comment: If i write whole big xml file in contents , still it pops that there is a syntax error in that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if the XML is provided as a [triple-quoted string](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html?highlight=triple#strings). This allows you to include unescaped quotes within the string.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

contents = """
<foo>
<bar key="value">text</bar>
</foo>"""

xml = ET.fromstring(contents)
print xml.find('./bar').attrib['key']
```